# How to check each line of the output of my previous Linux command in shell

Tags: shell

I have a script in which I run a command in remote machine using ssh and the output of that is as follows:

```
admin@dear:~/>: mccli checkpoint show

0,23000,CLI command completed successfully.

Tag                  Time                       Validated   Deletable    
.................    .......................    .........   .............

cp.20141212170053    2014-12-12 09:00:53 PST    Validated   No    
cp.20141212170337    2014-12-12 09:03:37 PST                No
```

Now, I have to take this output and needs to pick the value in Tag column for those which has `" "` (no entry) in validated column. So that I have an operation to perform with that tag value. Here the second row doesn't have the entry under validated column. I will try to put the output more clear: 
in the first row,

```
cp.20141212170053 - 1st column value (under Tag)    
2014-12-12 09:00:53 PST - 2nd column value (under Time)    
Validated - 3rd column value (under Validated)    
No - 4th column value (under Deletable)
```

I tried by taking the whole output into an array and checking for the same.
But, I am not able to proceed here. I am losing the logic to get this done.

How can I detect these lines?

Comment: I will make that command output more clear.

Comment: are the times always in PST?

Comment: yes .. the time is always in PST

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sed version of doing same thing:

```
mccli checkpoint show | sed -rne '/^(cp.[0-9]+).*Validated.*$/ !{s/^(cp.[0-9]+).*$/\1/p}'
```

`/^(cp.[0-9]+).*Validated.*$/` this part searchs for lines start with `cp.` and include `Validated`. With `!` we can have `{s/^(cp.[0-9]+).*$/\1/p}` run on lines that do not have that pattern. So actually below lines are processed but they don't start with `cp.[0-9]+`, so not get printed. Check [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for how to use sed.

```
0,23000,CLI command completed successfully.

Tag                    Time     Validated   Deletable    
................. ......................  ............  .............
cp.20141212170337    2014-12-12 09:03:37 PST                No
```

Comment: Thanks Juji, this worked. But, I  dint clearly understand the command you gave to me. Can you be more detail of this command?

Comment: @Jkreddy. I add some explanation in the answer. Check it out. Please vote up if that helps.

Comment: I couldn't vote as I am new to this site and I need 15 reputation for the same ... thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command:

```
mccli checkpoint show | awk -F ' {2,}' '/ PST/ && $(NF-2) != "Validated"{print $1}'
cp.20141212170337
```

- It assumes input field separator as 2 or more spaces.
- Since time is always in `PST` it just checks the timezone name.

In case you don't want to check for value `Validated` then you can also use:

```
awk -F ' {2,}' '/ PST/ && NF<4{print $1}'
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I tried this and it worked for this two row entries.My output of this command always varies and my fields are not constant. The output grows each time. Can I use this with the growing output to check for the validated column in each row? please clarify

Comment: Yes this should work as long as structure of your output remains same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you want to keep the header lines, so I'm discarding them (NR>6).  Some very simple solutions are:

```
mccli ... | awk 'NR>6 && NF<6'
mccli ... | awk 'NR>6 && !/Validated/'
```

If you want to keep the header lines, change `&&` to `||`.